# Bézout's coefficients, modular inverse

Tags: modular-arithmetic, solution-verification, euclidean-algorithm

I have to find $14^{-1} (\mod 17)$

I made the equation,
$$14x+17y=1$$
By Euclidean division algorithm-
$$ 17=14\times1+3 \\ 14=3\times4 +2\\3=2\times1+1$$
If I reverse the process then,
$$1=3-2\times1 \\=3-(14-3\times4)\times1 \\= 3-[14-(17-14\times1)\times4]\times1$$

But this doesn't seem to in the required form...

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Oh nevermind. I could just substitute 3 again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is right so far. You just need to note that $3 = 17 - 14$, so you have:

$$1 =(17-14)-[14-(17-14\times1)\times4]\times1$$
$$=(17-14)-[14-(17-14)\times4]$$
$$=(17-14)-[14-(17 \times 4-14\times 4)]$$
$$=(17-14)-[-17 \times 4 \color{red}{+}14 \times 5]$$
$$=(17-14) + 17 \times 4 -14 \times 5]$$
$$=17 \times 5-14 \times 6$$

Comment: Yeah.. I figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

You'd better use the standard layout of the *extended Euclidean algorithm*, which is based on the observation that  *all* remainders are linear combinations of $14$ and $17$:

\begin{array}{rrrr}
r_i &u_i&v_i&q_i \\
\hline
17&0&1\\
14&1&0&1\\
\hline
3&-1&1&4 \\
2&5&-4&1 \\
1&\color{red}{-6}&\color{red}{5} \\
\hline
\end{array}

(results inductively from the relation $r_{i-1}=q_ir_i+r_{i+1}$, rewritten as
$$r_{i+1}=r_{i-1}-q_ir_i)$$

Comment: I've spotted a small typo: you meant to say 'all remainders are linear combinations of $14$ and $17$'.

Comment: @TobyMak: From time to time, I only brush keys on my keyboard, and I forget to check… Thanks!